# Insufficient privileges for `run-instance` when enabling InstanceMetadataTags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a problem where I can't understand why it works like that.

I have a CloudFormation template, which give the following access rights:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - ec2:RunInstances
    - ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute
  Resource:
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':instance/*']]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':key-pair/*']]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':security-group/', Ref: DBSecurityGroup ]]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':volume/*']]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':network-interface/**']]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':subnet/', Ref: Subnet ]]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:' ,Ref: 'AWS::Region', ':',Ref: 'AWS::AccountId', ':placement-group/*']]
    - 'Fn::Join': [ '', [ 'arn:aws:ec2:',Ref: 'AWS::Region', '::image/ami-**']]
```

to the machines.

The machines can call `run-instances` using this role, everything works fine.

If I enable meta-data tags, like this:

```
  InstanceEnableTagsMetadata:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        MetadataOptions:
          InstanceMetadataTags: enabled
```

`run-instance` calls stop working with insufficient privileges.

Error messages looks like this:

```
API: ec2:RunInstances You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: OTMSE3dUu3XO...
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel: Added the error message to the question

Comment: Please, try to decode this message. This link may be helpful: https://github.com/aws/aws-parallelcluster/issues/372

Comment: Can you try adding `- ec2:CreateTags` to the actions?

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel: Yes, it was the problem. I described it in details as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I decode the encoded message, I get the following:

```
$ aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message Uz9... \
| jq -r .DecodedMessage | jq .
# [here comes a big JSON with details]
```

We see in the decoding, that the failed action is `launch-template`:

```
        {
          "key": "aws:Resource",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "launch-template/lt-"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

That means, `launch-template` should be added to the list of allowed actions.

(thanks to @ZabielskiGabriel for the hint)